# How to set redirect URI with pattern for OAuth 2 with Google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to have multiple websites using same google account for oAuth authentication. The websites are generated and deployed dynamically and follows a same path pattern. So the redirect URI will change for each website and each URL individually cannot be added in Google developer console. Is it possible to add any pattern or directory as redirect URI.

### My websites will follow the below pattern

```
wwww.domain.com/demo/<number>/oauth/google.html  

How can I keep <number> dynamic in the redirect URI?
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to add any pattern or directory as redirect URI?**

No.

You'll need to implement a proxy that Google redirects to which in turn redirects (or posts) to the actual oauthhandler.

NB Having xxxx.html as your your redirect URL is unusual as it would normally be some sort of server logic (a Java servlet, php page, etc). Are you sure you've understood what the redirect URl is doing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure I know what a redirect URL is. But my requirement is different where I allow users to create their website and deploy it in some directory and test. When users are testing oAuth inside their website I use my Google account. So I had to allow multiple redirect URL but cannot add all of them manually in Google account.

Comment: That's right. That's why you need to oauth via a proxy. Can you explain what "google.html" is? If it's a static web page, then it's (almost certainly) wrong.