# Sub-domain causing issue in uploading file to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, subdomain

I am trying to upload files to Google-Drive from my website using Java-script file it provides after creating app. While creating app on Google Drive for this I have added Authorized redirect URI & Authorized JavaScript origins domains like "www.mydomain.com". But now, my website URL contains sub-domain like "www.subdomain.mydomain.com". This sub-domain changes with the users.

When I try to upload to Google-Drive from such URL then Gogole-Drive is responding with error message **origin_mismatch**. I know it is because of URL registered (while creating app on Google-Drive) is different then URL from where I am trying to upload.

So, how can I upload files to Google-Drive from URL which contains sub-domain and it (sub-domain) changes with users.

Comment: dup of this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30808802/2213940 (can't mark dup as answer there isnt marked accepted)

Comment: possible duplicate of [google oauth2 redirect\_uri with several parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722062/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-with-several-parameters)

Comment: found another one to mark as dup (thou first one is closer to the o.p.)